# Taking a snapshot of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer's view

Tags: ios, uiview, webrtc, avcapturesession

I'm using WebRTC to build a video chat between two users. I want to take a snapshot of the `localView` view, which shows one of the persons.

This is my class with the `configureLocalPreview` method which connects the video streams with the UIViews:

```
@IBOutlet var remoteView: RTCEAGLVideoView!
@IBOutlet var localView: UIView!

var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
var videoSource: RTCAVFoundationVideoSource?
var videoTrack: RTCVideoTrack?

func configureLocalPreview() {
    self.videoTrack = self.signaling.localMediaStream.self.videoTracks.first as! RTCVideoTrack?
    self.videoSource = (self.videoTrack?.source as? RTCAVFoundationVideoSource)
    self.captureSession = self.videoSource?.self.captureSession

    self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.init(session: self.captureSession)
    self.previewLayer.frame = self.localView.bounds
    self.localView.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
    self.localView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    //self.localView.layer.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
}
```

At the place I want to access the snapshot, I call:

```
self.localView.pb_takeSnapshot()
```

`pb_takeSnapshot` comes from a UIView extension which I found in another post. It's defined like this:

```
extension UIView {
    func pb_takeSnapshot() -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

    drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
    }
}
```

When I take a look at the image in the Xcode debugger, it looks completely green and the person, which I can see on the iphone screen (inside that view), isn't there:

[image: screenshot of the snapshot]

What could the reason that the person isn't visible? Is it somehow just not possible to make a snaphot of a stream? Thank you for taking a look!

Answer (score 3):

Because `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` is implemented as an OpenGL layer you can't use regular CoreGraphic's context. I can suggest trying to access raw data.

Add `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` with delegate:

```
previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)

let captureVideoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
captureVideoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
captureSession?.addOutput(captureVideoOutput)

previewLayer.frame = localView.bounds
```

Conform your controller (or whatever) to `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`.

Declare `shouldCaptureFrame` variable and set it up whenever you need to take a picture.

```
var shouldCaptureFrame: Bool = false
...
func takeSnapshot() {
  shouldCaptureFrame = true
}
```

And implement `didOutputSampleBuffer` from delegate:

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
  if !shouldCaptureFrame {
    return
  }

  let image = UIImage.from(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer)
  shouldCaptureFrame = false
}
```

Finally, the extension with `from(sampleBuffer:)` function:

```
extension UIImage {

    static func from(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) -> UIImage? {
        guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
          return nil
        }
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        let baseAddresses = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let context = CGContext(
            data: baseAddresses,
            width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer),
            height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer),
            bitsPerComponent: 8,
            bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer),
            space: colorSpace,
            bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue
        )
        let quartzImage = context?.makeImage()
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

        if let quartzImage = quartzImage {
          let image = UIImage(cgImage: quartzImage)
          return image
        }

        return nil
    }

}
```

Comment: For me it always returns context as nil.

Answer (score 3):

You should create the localView using the RTCEAGLVideoView instead of UIView. I am using the same for my localView and able to take the snapshot using the same code snippet as mentioned in your post.

Below is the sample code which will start your camera and show the local preview:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,RTCEAGLVideoViewDelegate {

var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
var previewLayer :AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var peerConnectionFactory: RTCPeerConnectionFactory!
var videoSource:RTCAVFoundationVideoSource!
var localTrack :RTCVideoTrack!

@IBOutlet var myView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    /*myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                 y: 0,
                                 width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width,
                                 height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height))*/
    startCamera()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

fileprivate func startCamera() {

    peerConnectionFactory = RTCPeerConnectionFactory()
    RTCInitializeSSL();
    RTCSetupInternalTracer();
    RTCSetMinDebugLogLevel(RTCLoggingSeverity.info)

    videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.avFoundationVideoSource(with: nil);


    localTrack  = peerConnectionFactory.videoTrack(with: videoSource, trackId: "ARDAMSv0")



    let localScaleX = CGFloat(1.0)
    let localView : RTCEAGLVideoView = RTCEAGLVideoView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    self.view.insertSubview(localView, at: 1)
    localView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    localView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: localScaleX, y: 1)

    localTrack.add(localView)
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //previewLayer?.frame.size = myView.frame.size
}

func videoView(_ videoView: RTCEAGLVideoView, didChangeVideoSize size: CGSize) {
    print("Inside didChangeVideoSize")
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm a little confused how the actual code snipped would look like, though, as I've tried so many different code versions.

Comment: @Linus I have updated the post with sample code snippet you can use to start the camera and see the local preview.

Answer (score 1):

For the WebRTC video layer you should use `RTCEAGLVideoView` for the views. For more details take a look at these WebRTC sample application which is on here [AppRTC App](https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios)