# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer rect to jpeg data?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

I am looking for a way to take a CGRect defining a portion of a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer and turn its content into jpeg data.

So is there a way to snapshot a portion of a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer into jpeg?

I originally said CALayer, but I should have said AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer. I am not able to render into an image the content of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.

I might have to close this question and start it over with "AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer" instead?

Comment: "I might have to close this question and start it over with "AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer" instead?" You certainly wrote the question in a misleading way, eh. You can't really delete your question at this point, since people have put time and effort into answering it. But you can go a long way towards understanding the problem by doing a little searching. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42608915/taking-a-snapshot-of-avcapturevideopreviewlayers-view will make it very clear to you what kind of thing you would have to do in order to "capture" what is displayed in a video preview.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397899/avcapturevideopreviewlayer-taking-a-snapshot

Answer (score 1):

Only a UIImage has jpeg data. So render the whole layer into a UIImage, crop the UIImage as desired (I assume you know how to do that), and extract the jpeg data.

Comment: I see, so, I think I am wondering if there is a way to get a CALayer out of the just a portion of the original CALayer first, and then use the smaller CALayer to render to UIImage?

Comment: Well, what are you really trying to do? What is this layer and what's in it? What's the exact actual problem to be solved? Why does it matter which one you crop?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason there is no CALayer api to can't draw part of the layer (possibly because the discontinuous read from graphics memory is expensive), so just rasterize the whole thing then crop out the portion that you need and convert it to jpg.  Here is a playground example:

```
import PlaygroundSupport

let label = UILabel()
label.text = "test"
label.sizeToFit()
let layerImage = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: label.bounds).image { context in
  label.layer.draw(in: context.cgContext)
}
let cropRect = label.bounds.inset(by: .init(top: 2, left: 2, bottom: 2, right: 2))
let croppedImage = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: .init(origin: .zero, size: cropRect.size)).image { context in
  layerImage.draw(at: .init(x: (cropRect.size.width - layerImage.size.width) / 2, y: (cropRect.size.height - layerImage.size.height) / 2))
}
let jpg = croppedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
```

Comment: This is basically the same as what I said, isn't it?

Comment: Also is `label.layer.draw` really what you mean?